# Request method 'POST' not supported?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

While trying to return json object from spring controller to jQuery ajax in the jsp getting error as "Request method 'POST' not supported".

```
function fnMicEdit(){     
    var value=$( 'input[name=check]:checked' ).val();
    alert(value);
       $.ajax({
               type:'get',
               url:'getMicModule.htm',
               data:{radiovalue:value},
               dataType: "json",
               cache:false,
               success : function(data) {
                       $("#popup").html(data);
               },
               error:function(){
                       alert('error');
               }
           });
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMicModule",method=RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody MicDataBean GetModuleData(HttpSession session,@RequestParam("radiovalue") String radiovalue){
    System.out.println(radiovalue);
    Map<String, MicDataBean> mapObj = (Map<String, MicDataBean>) session.getAttribute("mapData");
    MicDataBean micDataBean1 = mapObj.get(radiovalue);
    System.out.println(micDataBean1);
    return micDataBean1;
}
```

Comment: You don't even read the answers from the guy that is trying to help you below.

Comment: Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your should change something there

**FIRST**

you are pointing to a wrong url resource

```
/getMicModule
```

instead this one

```
getMicModule.htm
```

**SECOND**

change in your method

```
method=RequestMethod.GET
```

to

```
method=RequestMethod.POST
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but still I am getting this error.

Comment: try changing in your client app this line  `type:'get'`, to  `type:'post'`,

Comment: changed client as well as server, but still error is there.

Comment: I see you are pointing to a wrong api url plz try my update and let me know